# C++17 Default template arguments: invalid use of template-name without an argument list

Tags: c++, templates, c++17

With C++17, you can do class template argument deduction in main like in the following example:

```
template<class T = int>
struct X{};

int main()
{
    X myX;
}
```

Why is template argument deduction not allowed for data members?

```
template<class T = int>
struct X{};

struct Y
{
   X myX;
};

int main()
{
   Y myY;
}
```

**error: invalid use of template-name ‘X’ without an argument list X myX;**

Comment: Not about CTAD, but some of the arguments are similar: [auto-type members](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3897.html)

Comment: Your example doesn’t, er, deduce anything.  If you just want to use the default template argument, just write `X<>`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I wasn't involved into the decision, however, I do see some problems in allowing it. Let's assume the following code:

```
template<class T = int>
struct X
{
    X(T t = T{}) {}
};
```

This makes your variable still OK:

```
int main()
{
     Y myY;
}
```

However, what if Y has a constructor that's implemented in a separate file?

```
struct Y
{
    Y();
    X myX{'a'};
};

Y::Y() : myX{0.0} {}
```

Do we in this case expect `myX` to be `X<int>` or `X<double>` or `X<char>`?

I can see that there can be confusion about this. As the standards commite can't revert it's decisions, it's better to take a small step that's certain and see if people need it and what they expect to happen.

Comment: Especially if the implementation of the constructor is not in the header but in the cpp-file, code from the cpp-file would influence the type of the member in the header file. This would not work with the manner in which C++ is compiled and linked (for the same reasons why we have to put the definitions of templated functions in the header files, too).

Comment: Don't really need a separate file for that example, even an inline `Y() : myX{0.0} {}` is pretty demonstrative.

Comment: About whether people need it, here is an example where I would find it handy: Let's suppose we have a (non-templated) class Z and 1000 other classes that have a Z member. At some point we decide that Z should be changed to a template class. I will specify the appropriate default template, but If I don’t want to change the name of the class, I will need to put a <> to the Z members of the 1000 classes, which is not nice. There are likely much more important use cases. Maybe there is a good set of rules that can be embodied in future C++ versions for the cases like the one in your answer.

Comment: `using Z = ZTemplate<>;`?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but I see a downside with that as well, that's why I wrote "if I don't want to change the name of the class". With `using Z = ZTemplate<> ` we would have two different names: the classes that need the default template would have members with type Z which is great, but the others would have members with type `ZTemplate<something>` instead of `Z<something>` which would be nicer imo.